# How to add a new category to content

Tags: modx

I'm a complete Modx newbie and I'm trying to update an existing website. My goal is to add a new category to some pages as shown in the table below:

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the documentation for this here https://bobsguides.com/creating-a-new-category.html

```
To create a new Category

Click on the Elements tab in the tree at the left in the Manager
Right-click on the "Categories" folder in the Element tree
Select "New Category"
Enter a Name for your new Category
(Optional) Enter a parent Category if you want to have Categories within Categories
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems your question about MIGX TV functionality, this is how you should solve this:

1. Update your MIGX TV with the next category field (in Form tabs):

```html
{"field":"category", "caption":"category", "inputTVtype":"listbox",
     "inputOptionValues":"@EVAL return $modx->runSnippet('getCategoryList');"}
```

2. Create snippet `getCategoryList` with next code inside:

```html
<?php
$result = array();
$c = $modx->newQuery('modCategory');
$c->sortby('category','ASC');
$categories = $modx->getCollection('modCategory',$c);
foreach($categories as $category){
   $result[] = $category->get('category')."==".$category->get('category');
}
return implode("||", $result);
```